# How to list all the apis of rails app for client developer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest

I'm learning and developing in rails for providing RESTful apis only. But I need some way to list all the apis so that client app developer can view them and may be test them using the listing page. Something like asp.net provides. Is there any gem that can list all the APIs and the input parameters required for them. I'm thinking that it may have something to do with route file but I could not figure out much.

Answer (score 0):

There are few documentation tools which can be used for such purposes, You can explore how [yardoc](http://yardoc.org/) works.

Comment: Thanks saurabh. I'll look into this tool. Can it be used to generate api testing pages too so that developer can provide input and check the response? I'm trying to achieve some like wsdl for my APIs.

Comment: No, This is just for documentation purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [api-pie](https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails) gem. It will be very useful gem for API document.

Answer (score 0):

I think get all api from routes will be a good way.
Here is how can you get all routes for your app.(from `rake routes` task)

```
all_routes = Rails.application.routes.routes
require 'action_dispatch/routing/inspector'
inspector = ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesInspector.new(all_routes)
puts inspector.format(ActionDispatch::Routing::ConsoleFormatter.new, ENV['CONTROLLER'])
```